# value not appearing in data table jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying to get value from 7 classes, for 7 columns

for interval one, interval two and so on for each student I have >

but the data table get's empty, but Java code is working fine.

I think the problem in html code tags

here is:

```
</h:form>

        <h:form id="hesham1">
        <p:scrollPanel style="width:100%;height:100%"> 
            <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" id="hesham" encoding="windows-1256"  dir="rtl" emptyMessage="لا يوجد بيانات او تأكد من البيانات المستعلم عنها">
            <f:facet name="header">  
        الاستعلام عن صف 2-10 
    </f:facet>

                    <p:columnGroup type="header">  
        <p:row>  
            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="اسم الطالب"/>  
            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="التاريخ" /> 
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الاولى" style="text-align: center;"/> 
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الثانية" style="text-align: center;"/>  
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الثالثة" style="text-align: center;"/> 
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الرابعة" style="text-align: center;"/> 
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الخامسة" style="text-align: center;"/> 
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة السادسة" style="text-align: center;"/> 
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة السابعة" style="text-align: center;"/> 
        </p:row>  

        <p:row>  
            <p:column headerText="المعلم" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{car.teachers}" /> 
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="الماده" > 
              </p:column> 
            <p:column headerText="الحالة" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{car.state}" />
             </p:column> 

                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval2.teachers2}" /> 
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="الماده" />  
            <p:column headerText="الحالة" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval2.state2}" />
             </p:column> 


                                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval3.teachers3}" /> 
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="الماده" />  
            <p:column headerText="الحالة" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval3.state3}" />
             </p:column>  


                                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval4.teachers4}" /> 
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="الماده" />  
            <p:column headerText="الحالة" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval4.state4}" />
             </p:column> 


                                    <p:column headerText="المعلم" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval5.teachers5}" /> 
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="الماده" />  
                           <p:column headerText="الحالة" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval5.state5}" />
            </p:column> 

                                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval6.teachers6}" /> 
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="الماده" />  
            <p:column headerText="الحالة" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval6.state6}" />
             </p:column> 


                                     <p:column headerText="المعلم" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval7.teachers7}" /> 
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="الماده" />  
            <p:column headerText="الحالة" > 
            <h:outputText value="#{interval7.state7}" />
             </p:column> 


        </p:row>  
    </p:columnGroup> 





                <f:facet name="footer">  
        اجمالي عدد الاستعلامات #{fn:length(tableBean.carsSmall)}   
    </f:facet>

            </p:dataTable>
            </p:scrollPanel> 
            <br />
            <h:commandButton value="طباعة التقرير" type="button"
                icon="ui-icon-print">
                <p:printer target="hesham" />
            </h:commandButton>

        </h:form>
```

Comment: If you mean the datatable is all emplty, then try to make sure that the list `carsSmall` is not empty in the managed-bean.

Comment: carsSmall is not empty I'm sure

Comment: Is the dataTable is all empty ? is there any error/exception ?

Comment: yes all empty no there is no error , #{fn:length(tableBean.carsSmall)} return 12 , so there is carsSmall but not displaying in rows

Comment: Maybe the display's way is not correct, like missing getters..

Comment: i have tired it with anouther html with datatabe without column group and it works . so java code works but html not work

Answer (score 0):

Um.. you simply don't have a table *body* here. Everything you have is an enormous header, incorrectly referencing the iteration variable and a giant footer.

See [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableGrouping.jsf) for how it's done properly, the `p:columnGroup` only enclosing the *header*:

```
<p:dataTable id="salesTable" var="sale" value="#{tableBean.sales}">

    <f:facet name="header">
        Sales/Profits of Manufacturers
    </f:facet>

    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Manufacturer" />
            <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Sales" />
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="Sales Count" />
            <p:column headerText="Profit" />
        </p:row>
     </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column>
        #{sale.manufacturer}
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        #{sale.lastYearProfit}%
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```